# C++ Array Resize crash

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, crash, resize

I have a simple array class that uses template and have a size. I want to Resize it whenever it's full, but my program keeps crashing. 
the code is like this:

```
    template<class T>
class Buffer:public File_ptr
{

    unsigned int siz;
    T *data;


public:

    ///konstruktor(size,filename,openmode)
    Buffer(unsigned int s=50,const char* n, const char* m):File_ptr(n,m),siz(s)
    {
        data= new T[siz];
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<siz; ++i)
        {
            data[i]=0;
        };
    };

    ///destruktor
    ~Buffer()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    ///operator[]
    T& operator[](unsigned int i)
    {
        if(i>siz)
        {
            unsigned int newsize=siz*2;
            T* tmp=new T[newsize];
            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < siz; j++)
            {
                tmp[j] = data[j];
            }
            siz=newsize;
            delete[] data;
            data=tmp;
            delete[] tmp;
        };
        return data[i];
    }

};
```

the error comes at the operator[].(at least i think).
The main program is like this :

```
int main()
{
   Buffer<int> k(20,"k.txt","w");
   Buffer<char*> s(20,"s.txt","w");
   k.printfile("HEY");
   s.printfile(5);
   for(unsigned int i=0;i<23;i++){
    s[i]="Hey";
    cout << s[i] << endl;
   }


return 0;
}
```

Any help would be great! :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a segmentation fault, because you are deleting memory twice.

```
data=tmp;
delete[] tmp;
```

Here, you assign `data` the memory location of `tmp`. So far so good, `data` and `tmp` point to the same memory region. But now you `delete[] temp;`, and so the memory region is deleted. But because `data` is also pointing to it, `data` is also no longer valid to be used as pointer (like `tmp`).

Then, with `return data[i];` you are trying to access that memory, but you deleted it! So you get a segmentation fault.

You can fix this by **not** `delete[] tmp;`, because then `data` points to a valid memory location, and everything is good :)

Answer (score 0):

You delete your fresh array still referenced by `tmp` in the `operator[]`. As this is the new array referenced by `data`, you inevitably run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues.  The first issue is that you delete the memory that `tmp` points to which is also what `data` now points to.  This means the next time the array grows you are accessing a deleted pointer which is undefined behavior.

A second issue is that `if(i>siz)` checks is `i` is past the end of the array but you never check to see `i` is also greater than `newsize`.  You need to set `newsize` to the largest of `siz * 2` and `i`.  Also it is is un-intuitive for the operator[] to grow the container.  When you call `[]` with a size larger than the container has that should be an error instead of re-sizing the array.